# Pop index out of range python

Tags: python

I am trying to get certain parts off a database. I am using pymongo and have got it into a list in my script. I am trying to use the `pop()` method to remove certain parts of the list.

> [{'_id': ObjectId('5fe357f3aa9a0fad99161370'), 'twitch': 'twitchusername', 'serverID': 791003444256178208, 'type': 'user'}]

I would like to just keep the 'twitchusername'. However when I do `mylist.pop(4)` I get the error:

> Pop index out of range

How would I go around this? Thanks :)

I will leave my code below:

````
myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("link")
mydb = myclient["Cluster0"]
mycol = mydb["live"]

myquery = { "type": "user" }

array = []

array = list(mycol.find(myquery))

print(array)

array1 = mylist.pop(4)```
````

Comment: That list only contains a single element (a dictionary). To get the name out of the first dictionary, you'd do `mylist[0]['twitch']`.

Comment: Your `array` (which is not actually an array but a list) has only one item: a dictionary. This is why you can't `pop()` the 5th item (index `4`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want the value from the `twitch` key, then you can filter out the other columns in the `find` and then iterate the resulting data; example would be:

```
cursor = mycol.find({ "type": "user" }, {'_id': 0, 'twitch': 1})

for item in cursor:
    print(item.get('twitch'))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks this worked. Is there a way I can transfer it to a variable?

Comment: sure, just do `x = item.get('twitch')` instead of the print.

Answer (score 0):

**Parameter:**
"index (optional) - The value at index is
popped out and removed.

If the index is not given, then the last
element is popped out and removed."

**Exception:**
"When the index is out of range, it returns IndexError"

I just think your array is empty or length <= 4 - check it at 1st...